# Mostrar un dato desde una tabla relacionada Datatable

Tags: laravel, ajax, nodejs, datatables

Estoy haciendo una tabla en dataTable y me encontre con un problema, tengo que mostrar los datos de un vehiculo y entre esos datos se encuentra la **"marca"** que en la base de datos es una tabla diferente a la tabla vehiculos, pero que esta relacionada. Lo que pasa es que en la tabla obviamente me muestra el id si consulto el campo relacionado.

[image: asi se visualiza la "marca"]

Quiero que en lugar de visualizar el id del campo relaciona, se muestre el nombre de la marca, quiero saber si es posible hacer algo como: **{{ $vehiculo->marcas->marca }}** que es como lo hacia normalmente mediante los modelos de laravel.

Mi controlador esta asi:

```
public function vehiculoData()
{

    return Datatables()
            ->eloquent(Vehiculo::query())
            ->addColumn('btn', 'vehiculos.actions')
            ->rawColumns(['btn'])
            ->toJson();
}
```

Mi vista es esta:

```
@section('contenido')
  <table class="table table-bordered" id="vehiculos-table">
     <thead>
         <tr>
             <th width="75px">Placa</th>
             <th>Marca</th>
             <th>Modelo</th>
             <th>Color</th>
             <th width="80px">&nbsp;</th>
         </tr>
     </thead>
  </table>
 @stop
@push('scripts')
<script>
$(function() {
    $('#vehiculos-table').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: '{!! route('datatables.vehiculo') !!}',
        columns: [
        { data: 'placa', name: 'placa' },
        { data: 'marca_vehiculo_id', name: 'marca_vehiculo_id' },
        { data: 'modelo', name: 'modelo' },
        { data: 'color', name: 'color' },
        { data: 'btn' }
    ]
   });
 });
 </script>
@endpush
```

Estoy empezando a aprender esta herramienta y agradezco la ayuda de antemano...

Answer (score 0):

#### [Eloquent Datatable con Eager Loading. Model Belongs To Demo](https://datatables.yajrabox.com/relation/belongs-to)

En tu controller puedes cargar con eager loading la relación `marca` usando la api de Laravel `Vehiculo::with('marca');`.

```
$model = Vehiculo::with('marca')->select('vehiculos.*');

return DataTables()
            ->eloquent($model)
            ->addColumn('btn', 'vehiculos.actions')
            ->rawColumns(['btn'])
            ->toJson();
```

Y en la vista arreglas una columna para que devuelva un atributo de esa relación: `{ data: 'marca.nombre', name: 'marca.nombre' },`

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('#vehiculos-table').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: '{!! route('datatables.vehiculo') !!}',
        columns: [
            { data: 'placa', name: 'vehiculo.placa' },
            { data: 'marca.nombre', name: 'marca.nombre' },
            { data: 'modelo', name: 'vehiculo.modelo' },
            { data: 'color', name: 'vehiculo.color' },
            { data: 'btn' }
        ]
   });
 });
 </script>
```

Donde:

`vehiculo` es el modelo Vehiculo.

`marca` representa la relación `marca` del modelo `Vehiculo`.

`placa`,`modelo`,`color` y `nombre` representan el atributo que quieres mostrar.

Comment: Muchas gracias, muy clara la explicación

Comment: @JavierParra vale, me alegra que te haya servido.